# Raising the floor function to a power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

I've made a few plots and noticed that $\lfloor

Is it true that for positive $x > 1$ and $n \in \mathbb N,\quad n>=2$ the following holds:

$$(\lfloor x \rfloor + 1)^n >= \lfloor x^n \rfloor $$

If it is, how can it be proven?
If it is not, will that at least hold when $n=2$?
I am interested in the latter case, actually.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you missing something in the description of what you noticed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lfloor x\rfloor +1 \gt x$, so $(\lfloor x\rfloor +1)^n\gt x^n$.  On the other hand, $\lfloor x^n\rfloor\leq x^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\lfloor x \rfloor + 1 \ge x$